# How to import substrate_primitives in order to use sr25519?

Tags: rust, substrate

I have the following dependencies in my `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[package]
name = "api-client-tutorial"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Supercomputing Systems AG <info@scs.ch>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
substrate-api-client = { git = "https://github.com/scs/substrate-api-client.git" }
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", features = ["derive"], version = "1.0.0", default-features = false }

[dependencies.primitives]
git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate"
rev = "3bf9540e72df5ecb3955845764dfee7dcdbb26b5"
package = "substrate-primitives"

[dependencies.keyring]
git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate"
rev = "3bf9540e72df5ecb3955845764dfee7dcdbb26b5"
package = "substrate-keyring"
```

I am unsure of the difference between `dependencies` section and `dependencies.primitives` section, but the package `substrate-primitives` is included in the primitives section.

I [have seen](https://docs.rs/substrate-primitives/1.0.0/substrate_primitives/sr25519/index.html) that `substrate_primitives` has the module `sr25519` I need to use, but when I try to import it in my code:

```
use substrate_api_client::{Api, node_metadata};
use substrate_primitives::sr25519;
fn main() {
    // instantiate an Api that connects to the given address
    let url = "127.0.0.1:9944";
    // if no signer is set in the whole program, we need to give to Api a specific type instead of an associated type
    // as during compilation the type needs to be defined.
    let api = Api::<sr25519::Pair>::new(format!("ws://{}", url));

    let meta = api.get_metadata();
    println!("Metadata:\n {}", node_metadata::pretty_format(&meta).unwrap());
}
```

I get the following error:

```
unresolved import `substrate_primitives`

use of undeclared type or module `substrate_primitives`rustc(E0432)
main.rs(2, 5): use of undeclared type or module `substrate_primitives`
```

How do I import sr25519 so that I can use the following line in my code?

```
let api = Api::<sr25519::Pair>::new(format!("ws://{}", url));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between tables under `[dependencies]` and the `[dependencies.primitives]` table is that the table for the `primitives` dependency is not inlined. You could also just inline the `primitives` dependency and put it under `[dependencies]` like that:

```
primitives = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", rev = "3bf9540e72df5ecb3955845764dfee7dcdbb26b5", package = "substrate-primitives" }
```

The [toml documentation](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml#user-content-table) can give you more details on tables and inline tables.

Regarding your problem. You cannot import the crate like that, because it is renamed to `primitives`. The `package` field specifies the real name of the dependency and the table name defines the new name which is used to import it inside your project. For details have a look at the [cargo documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#renaming-dependencies-in-cargotoml).

Your import should therefore look like this: `use primitives::sr25519;`